# What does an ideologically perfect solipsistic government look like?

Tags: government

A very large group of people find themselves together on a small continent with abundant natural resources. Each individual in the group is fully convinced that nothing exists outside of his or her own consciousness, but nonetheless, they cannot escape their own sense perceptions.

What kind of social structure or government would they form, if it is possible for them to organize at all?

Comment: What's an ideologically perfect solipsistic government?

Comment: A government run by solipsists which exemplifies their ideology perfectly, or at least perfectly exemplifies the way that people with that ideology would organize a government.

Comment: Please clarify why this doesn't belong on philosophy.SE or politics.SE.

Comment: With a little thought, I could argue why your scenario could morph into anarchist utopia and with a little more into *Lord of the Flies*, and with a little more into a dictatorship, and all would be valid.  VTC Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: What difference, if any, is there between not being able to escape their own sense perceptions and believing their sense perceptions to be real?

Comment: @ronjohn it has enough of a hypothetical component to be in our domain. It’s not asking a “should” or “ought”, which pushes it out of (or at least away from) philosophy SE, and politics SE only deals with standard model humans.

Comment: Unless the question is edited to explain what is to be understood by a "solipsistic government" there is no possible answer. Solipsism is a minor philosphical position; it has limited importance in metaphysics and no practical applications.

Comment: I'm voting to close (OK, I'm not, it was closed while I was typing this comment) because you haven't told us how you'll judge the best answer.  Worse, you probably can't.  I'll give you a hint, though.  A solpsistic culture would likely be intrinsically enochlophobic.

Comment: *"A government run by solipsists which exemplifies their ideology perfectly":* what ideology? Can you please name an author and a book discussing said ideology?

Comment: Solipsism is an extremely limiting belief in terms of the number of other things you can believe to be true while you are solipsist. Solipsism has an impact on beliefs about morality and obligation which can be interpolated easily with some googling.

Comment: It doesn't belong in philosophy because it pertains to a hypothetical society in a hypothetical world. This is world building

Comment: I haven't seen very many questions where the author explicitly stated criteria for judging best answer. I think the implied criteria is either "most interesting to the author" or "fits the rest of the author's world best", and I'd like if neither consideration affected your answer.

Comment: If you don't know what solipsism is, I'm fairly certain it's not my responsibility to provide you with reference material in my question.

Comment: The difference between not being able to escape senses and believing that they are real is: the sensations are really coming into your mind, and they can't be ignored, but they might not be real because there's no guarantee that they represent actual external phenomena.

Comment: We are in the process of requiring the critera.  It's part of the site's proposed description for closing questions as [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).  Questions like this are great candidates for our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions), where we can help you craft a good question before it's introduced to the main site.

Comment: `If you don't know what solipsism is, I'm fairly certain it's not my responsibility to provide you with reference material in my question.`  It is 100% your responsibility.  We are NOT your reserach service.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, then don't answer. How is any Q/A website not about research? I mean, if I knew the answer, then I wouldn't ask, so I'm researching by asking. I'm hoping that someone else who knows something I don't know will help me by answering.

Comment: But I appreciate the link to the sandbox. I'll keep it in mind if I have any more questions which are too theoretical.

Comment: @JBH While this question is troublesome, I'm with boxcartenant in this point. Solipsism is an established philosophical theory, a quick google search clears up. Writing a question does not require you to explain any established technical term.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher, That would make a good question for Meta.

Comment: @JBH Feel free to contribute: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313666/is-a-question-obliged-to-explain-established-technical-terms-that-are-unlikely-t

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher I added an answer to the Meta discussion on our Meta about this question [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6505/28789). In the second to last paragraph I talk a bit about providing reference material. You might be interested in reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with solipsism in these kinds of questions of society is that solipsism makes a lot of descriptive claims (what things are) but very few normative claims (what should we do about it). So solipsists could pretty much form any kind of society.

If I were to take a stab at it, I would say that it would likely be very hedonistic, with very little organized power structure (why would I let you lead me if you don't even really exist?) with very slow technological advancement.

The other problem with solipsism and societies is that the birth rate would likely be very very low. Because if you think that the world ends after your death, what incentive do you have to pass on your genes or give back to the world?

I'm not sure if I answered your question exactly, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Interesting and fun response. And especially I appreciate that you took a shot at it lol. My comments have been a little disappointing.

Comment: I would even go further on the third paragraph and propose that not only birth rate would be low but also sex (mutually agreed one, that is). A solipsist, as I see it, would only be after his own sexual pleasure, because why do the work to give the sexual partner pleasure, if the person doesn't exist? And vice versa, if the other person cannot give you any pleasure, why even take the step? I'd suppose this would mainly affect women, but not only.